# Is there a browser extension to pronounce the words?

Tags: resource-request, pronunciation

I might be missing some cool tools: Are there browser extensions to pronounce the words in some/several languages?

I know I can select a word, right-click, search, get dictionary result, and click on pronunciation. Is there a tool which makes it seamless?

Inspired by [this question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/76/is-duolingo-effective-in-learning-to-speak-languages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Translate Anywhere is available for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dictionary-anywhere/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/panel-view-for-google-tra/bcefgmhpbmghjcenbklchobmogjhaagl), and I believe for [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/dictionary-anewhere/) as well.

Basically, it opens Google™ Translate in a frame (of a customizable size) straight over your page. You select a text, right-click to invoke a Context Menu, and choose the option. The extension captures text selection and allows to choose source/target languages, too.

Google™ Translate, in turn, has "listen" button (I highlighted it with red circles).

[image: Google™ Translate Panel]

The integration with a ready-made service automatically provides with some nice features like remembering your recent requests in your Google account, and more.

Answer (score 2):

[Google dictionary extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en)

[image]

> With this extension, you can:
>
> 1) Double-click any word to view its definition in a small pop-up
>   bubble.
>
> 2) View the complete definition of any word or phrase using the
>   toolbar dictionary.
>
> 3) Store a history of words you've looked up, so you can practice them
>   later.
>
> Foreign words are automatically translated to your language of choice.
>
> Supported dictionaries:
>
> - Arabic
> - Brazilian Portuguese
> - Chinese (Simplified)
> - Chinese (Traditional)
> - Czech
> - Dutch
> - English (UK)
> - English (US)
> - French
> - German
> - Hindi
> - Italian
> - Japanese
> - Korean
> - Russian
> - Slovak
> - Spanish
> - Turkish

Answer (score 2):

[this extension](https://www.usefluent.co) does a bit more than translate words (it immerses you in vocab by switching a few words on every page to your target language), but it also does offer pronunciation. In general I've found it to be a great resource for taking vocab from the initial "learned" stage, to the "fluent" stage. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's cool plugin for Chrome. Freemium. Just Spanish and French for now, but interesting approach.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! A few friends of mine who are learning French swear by it